# Keep contents of a div together for printing in IE8

Tags: css, xhtml, printing, printing-web-page, page-break-inside

Given the following HTML document, I need to keep the "Table title" line on the same page as the `<table>` when being printed in IE8.

Despite the `page-break-inside:avoid;`, there is still a page break between the title and the table. My understanding of this suggests a page break should be avoided and the whole `div` pushed on to page 2.

The doctype is XHTML 1.0 Transitional, I have `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />` set to force IE8 into Standards Mode which [supposedly supports this syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc196971%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and I have verified the rendering is being done in standards mode by checking `document.compatMode == "CSS1Compat"`. The XHTML is valid.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" /> 
  <title>Page title</title>
</head>
  <body>
    <h1>Page content</h1>
    this is some content
    <br />which<br />should<br />push<br />the<br />table<br />below<br />on<br />to<br />the<br />next<br />page<br />but<br />the<br />table<br />should<br />be<br />kept<br />together<br />if<br />at<br />all<br />possible<br />please!

    <div style="page-break-inside:avoid;">
      <p><strong>Table title which needs to be kept with the table</strong></p>
      <table>
        <tr><td>one</td><td>two</td><td>three</td></tr>
        <tr><td>one</td><td>two</td><td>three</td></tr>
        <tr><td>one</td><td>two</td><td>three</td></tr>
        <tr><td>one</td><td>two</td><td>three</td></tr>
        <tr><td>one</td><td>two</td><td>three</td></tr>
        <tr><td>one</td><td>two</td><td>three</td></tr>
        <tr><td>one</td><td>two</td><td>three</td></tr>
        <tr><td>one</td><td>two</td><td>three</td></tr>
        <tr><td>one</td><td>two</td><td>three</td></tr>
        <tr><td>one</td><td>two</td><td>three</td></tr>
        <tr><td>one</td><td>two</td><td>three</td></tr>
        <tr><td>one</td><td>two</td><td>three</td></tr>
        <tr><td>one</td><td>two</td><td>three</td></tr>
        <tr><td>one</td><td>two</td><td>three</td></tr>
        <tr><td>one</td><td>two</td><td>three</td></tr>
        <tr><td>one</td><td>two</td><td>three</td></tr>
        <tr><td>one</td><td>two</td><td>three</td></tr>
        <tr><td>one</td><td>two</td><td>three</td></tr>
        <tr><td>one</td><td>two</td><td>three</td></tr>
        <tr><td>one</td><td>two</td><td>three</td></tr>
        <tr><td>one</td><td>two</td><td>three</td></tr>
        <tr><td>one</td><td>two</td><td>three</td></tr>
        <tr><td>one</td><td>two</td><td>three</td></tr>
        <tr><td>one</td><td>two</td><td>three</td></tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why aren't you using the `caption` element for the table header? then try putting the `page-break-inside: avoid;` inside the table element.

Comment: @whoabackoff - doesn't work any better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IE8 support for [this feature is buggy](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/page-break-inside).

> Although Internet Explorer for Windows version 8 supports the value avoid it is a little buggy in places. For example, if applied to a p element, the browser will try to avoid breaking the page inside the element as expected; but **if applied to a ul element, the whole list is not set to avoid as the list may span the two pages. That said, the individual list element will try to avoid having a page break inside.**

From this example, we can conclude it will try to not break the page inside the p, nor inside the table, but it won't combine both. You can test it by having a really long text in your `<p>`.

A way to fix this would be to include your title in your table :

```
  <table style="page-break-inside:avoid;" border="1">
    <tr><th colspan="3">Table title which needs to be kept with the table</th></tr>
    <tr><td>one</td><td>two</td><td>three</td></tr>
    <tr><td>one</td><td>two</td><td>three</td></tr>
    [...]
```

Comment: Hi Kraz - that's helpful, now I know what's going on. Thanks. Do you have any suggestions for a workaround? There is lots of tabular data which needs to be displayed - lots of tables - each of which needs to be kept with its title and some explanatory text.

Comment: Add your _table title_ inside your table, it's all I can see. Then skin your table and make the table header different. (I've edited my answer with an example.) Same for the explanatory text, put it in its own row and skin it (a css class maybe?).

Answer (score 1):

`page-break` only works on a paged media context, like `@media print`:

```
@media print {
  tr {
    page-break-inside:avoid;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `<th>` and add title

for example

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>your title</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>one</td>
        <td>two</td>
        <td>three</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS use `@ media`

```
@media print {
    tr th {
    page-break-inside:avoid;
    }
}
```

Recently i have created print version HTML it works fine! hope it helps you!